# How to run sshd with nix (not nixos) in container?

Tags: nix

The nixos/nix image is based on Alpinelinux. Installing openssh is done. But since there is no systemd, I need to bring up sshd myself.

The problem is that, there is no /etc/ssh/sshd_config. I see the file in nix store. But I am not sure what is the proper action.

Comment: Are you sure you need SSH in your container? Unless you're building a service on the SSH protocol, you probably want `docker exec -ti`

Comment: I am trying to make an isolated environment for desktop. So sshd is just a service runs there. I know LXC might be better option, but without a working image, it is not high priority.

Comment: Ok, cool. Did you try https://github.com/hercules-ci/arion? It's in an early stage, but it supports registry images, Nix images, NixOS services (leaky) and full NixOS. It can also use the host's Nix store for quick iteration before you build the real images.

Comment: No idea what is that. Let me check.